# Armadillo, how to grow a vector and get his size?

Tags: c++, linux, linear-algebra, armadillo

In my last question, *Ilmari Karonen* propose to me to solve the *Laplace* equation in discret mode. I'm using a grid and the four closest neighbours at each node to compute the unknown heights.

[image]

So the system to solve can be written with matrix :

**A(matrix nxn) * U(vector n, unknowns) = b(vector n, settled)**

last evening I looked around the web about linear algebra for C++. My choice is [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). But for now "U" and "b" are `std::map` :

```
std::map<std::pair<float,float>,float> b;
std::map<std::pair<float,float>,float> U;
.
.
.
if(g/*grid*/->getNode(r,c)->status == TO_COMPUTE){
          U.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(r,c),g->getNode(r,c)->y));
          /*right*/ if(g->getNode(r+1,c)->status == SETTLED) b.at(std::make_pair(r,c)) += g >getNode(r+1,c)->y;
          /*left */ if(g->getNode(r-1,c)->status == SETTLED) b.at(std::make_pair(r,c)) += g->getNode(r-1,c)->y;
          /*down */ if(g->getNode(r,c+1)->status == SETTLED) b.at(std::make_pair(r,c)) += g->getNode(r,c+1)->y;
          /*up   */ if(g->getNode(r,c-1)->status == SETTLED) b.at(std::make_pair(r,c)) += g->getNode(r,c-1)->y;
        }
```

and I think I will have then to get the size of "U" to create `arma::vec` and to parse the whole map with an `std::iterator` to transfer the values in my `arma::vec`. So I would like to know how to grow a `arma::vec` I'm looking for something like `std::vector::push_back()`, then I will replace my `std::map`. Also how can I get the size for a `arma::vec`?

note1 : the picture shows the contours and the points where I will compute the values, the grid with unknow value is at y=0, when the lower contour is at y=-0.2 and the upper contour at y=0.8

note2 : when my little (LINUX) program will be ready I will release the code on my bitbucket as a very tiny example of use of discret *Laplace* operator

## Update 26 Nov. 2013:

you can get the link to the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106591/what-kind-of-algorithm-for-generating-height-map-from-contour-line)

Comment: A `map<>` indexed by `pair<float,float>`?  You might want to read this to get some hints how to make that work reasonably (particularly Yakk's example):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684573/floating-point-keys-in-stdmap   If, that is, you _really_ want to index by pairs of floats.

Comment: I see, usually I'm using `std::pair<int,int>` I realize I was thinking in `int` I even wrote `+1` and `-1` instead of `+1.0f` and `-1.0f`. Thanks for pointing this out. If there is no way to grow a `arma::vec` I will rewrite this without `std::map` but I will create a structure for a better use and read

Comment: For performance critical code, functions like std::vector::push_back() are not very efficient. Sooner or later std::vector will need to re-allocate memory and copy all the data. It's more efficient to work out the required size first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Armadillo's [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html). For example, you can use [X.n_elem](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#attributes) to get the length of vector X. To resize a vector while preserving the data, use [.resize()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#resize_member).  To add a row or column to a matrix, use [.insert_rows() or .insert_cols()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#insert).

Note that resizing objects inside performance critical loops (whether they're Armadillo matrices/vectors or std::vector) is not efficient. It's far better to work out the correct size beforehand.